# Only get characters surrounded by " "

Tags: vb.net

I'm Currently writing a program that will convert my code into Pseudo Code but I'm having the problem that I cannot figure out how to get Only text that is surrounded by " " and comes after the word print.

Currently have

```
    Dim str() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split()
    If str.Contains("Print") Then

    End If
```

Nothing

Comment: You've tagged this both VB.Net and VBA. Please choose one. Also, why not elaborate a bit, for instance by giving an example of what you would have in Textbox1, and what you'd want as the result.

Comment: @DougGlancy Inside of TextBox1 would be java, I'm converting java to basic Pseudo Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way. Instead of splitting and then checking for `Print`, Check for `Print` first and then split it.

**Tried and Tested**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("Print") Then
        Dim ar As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.IndexOf("Print"))

        Dim splitted() As String = Split(ar, """")

        If splitted.Length > 1 Then MessageBox.Show(splitted(1))
    End If
End Sub
```

If the string is say `This "is" a great Print Job! "Nice Work"` then the above code should give you `Nice Work`